# How can I change the href text using javascript im stuck

Tags: html, href

i got stuck 4 hours ago and i cant figure this out, how can i make the balance to go from 0.13 to $50.13?

Here is the code:

```
<li class="notranslate" id="Mata" translate="no">
<a href="/wallet">Balance: $0.13</a></li>
```

Im trying to do this using the console in google chrome

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/wallet']")[0].text = "Balance: $50.13";`?

Comment: @VasilisG you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you set an id on the link like this:

```html
<a id="link" href="/wallet">Balance: $0.13</a>
```

Then you can use:

```js
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "Balance: $50.13";
```

If you are not able to set an id then you can do:

```js
document.querySelector("link[href='/wallet']").innerHTML = "Balance: $50.13";
```

The chrome inspect tool also has a feature where if you click the icon in the top-left of the tool, it will let you select an element from the page. After selecting an element, you can refer to it in the console as `$0`. So you after selecting the link you could do:

```js
$0.innerHTML = "Balance: $50.13";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have an `id` assigned to your `a` tag, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which will return a list of elements that match the specified selector.

Then, you can access each element using its index number, which in your case is `0`, since you have only one element.

To change the text, simply use the `text` property:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/wallet']")[0].text = "Balance: $50.13";
```